# I am not able to solve an error in flask for reset_password()

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

```
@app.route('/reset_password', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_request():
  if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
  form = RequestResetForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = user.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    send_reset_email(user)
    flash('An email has been sent with instructions to reset your password', 'info')
    return redirect(url_for('login_context'))
  return render_template('reset_request.html', title='Reset Password', form = form)
```

[image: this is the error!!]

this is what I coded. I want to create a reset password function. I am unable to decode what that error says.

error:

```
def reset_request():
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
 1315, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
 98, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
 1275, in add_url_rule
    rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try update

```
@app.route('/reset_password', method=['GET', 'POST'])
```

to

```
@app.route('/reset_password', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

and see if it solved your problem.